# Phrase.com what should I put in key title for ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have created a web app and I want to translate it to different langauges. I have found this nice site Phase.com but I am not sure how to use keys. How those keys connect to my html text? The title should be the same as

class etc so it can find this?